# Stop each loop in Pug

Tags: node.js, pug

Here is my mixin:

```
mixin treeview(...routes)
  each route in routes
    //- path is a variable which I passed from express
    if (path === route)
      li.treeview.active
        if block
          block
        //- stop right here
```

It seems like `break` in Javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **- break**

```
mixin treeview(...routes)
  each route in routes
    //- path is a variable which I passed from express
    if (path === route)
      li.treeview.active
        if block
          block
          - break
          //- stop right here
```

A simple [demo](http://codepen.io/clementvial/pen/BpJgdE)

Comment: The hyphen (-) sign tell Pug we are using inline JavaScript